# Mobile First 7.1 Application center install error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to install Mobile First 7.1 platform and the application server is websphere liberty 8.5.5.9. during install it throws below error in failed-install.log. (Database is DB2)

F:\Program Files\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server\WorklightServer\post-install.xml:332: The following error occurred while executing this line:
F:\Program Files\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server\WorklightServer\post-install.xml:2172: An error occured while reading file F:\Program Files\ibm\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\server1\server.xml. Error: null.

the line numbers shows error for Application center installation..

what could be the issue?

Comment: MFP7.1 on Liberty 8.5.5.9 is a supported scenario. Does your installation Manager show that DB connection is successful ?. Also, can you ensure you have file permission on the system.

Comment: Yes.DB connection is successful. and permissions are ok as i am installing as administrator with elevated rights..

Comment: please attach the logs

Comment: i installed the application center manually now as mentioned in the IBM articles and that works.

Comment: @VishalShah, please write the above as an answer to the question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

i installed the application center manually now as mentioned in the IBM articles and that works.